# How can I fix sign out bug on AWS Cognito with flutter?

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, dart

I'm doing an app using flutter that uses AWS Cognito for authentication, but every time the user sign of the app this black screen appears, I've searched but could not find out what is wrong, can anyone help me?

Here is my authentication code:

```
signIn(username, password, context) async {
try {
  SignInResult res =
      await Amplify.Auth.signIn(username: username, password: password);
  if (res.isSignedIn) {
    Navigator.of(context)
        .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
  }
  print(username);
} on AuthException catch (e) {
  print(e.message);
}
```

}

```
signOut() async {
try {
  await Amplify.Auth.signOut();
} on AuthException catch (e) {
  print(e.message);
}
```

}

And this is how I'm calling the function:

```
leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            AuthService().signOut();
            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/');
          },
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back)),
```

[the black screen that appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuTKG.jpg)

Comment: Can you also share the configuration of your user pool app client?

Comment: Sure, on the identity providers, it's all authorized and on the OAuth 2.0 this is what's marked: Authorization code grant

Comment: Do you have callbacks URLs configured for the login and logout?

Comment: No, just the standard configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When logging out your user with Cognito, you need to pass a redirect URI in your request, so Cognito knows what to do after the sign out has happened. This URI also has to be registered as a possible URL in your app client configuration, in order to determine whether or not this is intended or malicious behaviour.

As you've stated in the comments on your question, you have not configured any sign out URI. So Cognito redirects to a blank page since it has no information on how to proceed otherwise.

(edit)
[image: Screenshot of URL configuration Cognito]

Comment: oh okay, i'm a little new on the aws, can you show me how to do this?

Comment: Please see the following page in the user guide for more information: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-settings.html

Comment: i've tried to do the configuration and entered a myapp:// uri but it's still making the same problem

Comment: I've added a screenshot of a potential configuration. Obviously, you have to use URLs of your application and implement those endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

This issue appears to only affect android at the moment.

To overcome this issue, you can do a global sign out so that the browser redirect is skipped. Note that globalSignOut on iOS seems to trigger AWS auth exceptions which is why I used Platform.isAndroid.

```
import 'dart:io' show Platform;

final SignOutResult res = await Amplify.Auth.signOut(
        options: const SignOutOptions(globalSignOut: Platform.isAndroid),
      );
```

Comment: Is there any solution about that? Because let's say we have also web application and if we don't want to exit globally. How we can skip redirect thing?